# Which sql query is best performing on heavy and continues load , when fetching row with exact input match if exists, else common match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

In a SP, I am getting EmployeeId,UnitId,CategoryId as input parameter.

I need to search for given Input Parameters for the given Category Id 
In a large table (150 million records). Large table has clustered index on EmployeeId,UnitId,CategoryId.

The query should return exact match with input category id or if exact input category id is not found it should return row for category id = -1.
e.g.

```
`select * from LargeTable where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId and UnitId=@UnitID and category_id in (@CategoryId, -1)`
```

will it be best performing query or shall I write two query , first will look for exact match, if match is not found second query will execute and return row matching categoryid -1.

Which approach is best?

What will be the query to check and return exact match without searching table twice, if I go with second approach?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? it's a simple test to make...

Comment: @ZoharPeled not really for all possible input and their matching records in table. wondering if get a quick answer.

Comment: Write clear, readable code that expresses *what you want*. Also, separately, set performance *goals*. Then *measure* the code and see if it matches the goals. If it does, great, the job is done. If not, *then* pinpoint *where* the performance issue is. Don't try to learn 10 billion "performance" rules for writing code and then blindly apply them.

Comment: You don't have to test each possible input, just try 10 different category ids. if you see a consistent difference in performance, then go with the faster option.

Comment: any answer for my second question?

Comment: the answer is: it depends. to get a technically sound answer you must provide some tehnical data. the post contain only vague indication, a generic query, no info about indexes, columns or statistics: it is almost impossible to provide anything but vague answers. narrow down the issue and provide technical details.

Comment: You suggest the use of **IN (@CategoryId, -1)** but unless you actually store a record in that table with category_id  = -1 then using IN is redundant. If you do store a record in the table with category_id  = -1 then your query will return 2 rows if the @CategoryId is valid and one row it is invalid. This does not meet your stated requirement anyway.

Comment: You really want all columns from LargeTable ?
if yes then have clustered index on category_id  or NC on  category_id   with all column in leaf (NC with include).
query 

if exists (select * from LargeTable where category_id in (@CategoryId)
begin 
select * from LargeTable where category_id in (@CategoryId)
END 
ELSE
BEGIN 

select * from LargeTable where category_id in ( -1)
END

Comment: Change CI  to CategoryId,EmployeeId,UnitId, and see the magic

Answer (score 0):

I tried various ways, but the following gave best performance after testing in performance servers:

1) Create Temporary table with the same structure of LargeTable.

2) Insert all the primary column values from input parameter to the temp table.

3) Update the temp table with matching values with @CategoryId.

4) Update the temp table with matching values with -1, where temp table is not updated with @CategoryId.

5) return data from temp table.

Looks like spliting this query to two query gives some breathing space to SQL Server and thus it gives best SLA for long and heavy load.

Comment: share Large table indexes

Comment: there you go change it to CategoryId,EmployeeId,UnitId, and see the magic

Comment: sorry @NeerajPrasadSharma I forgot to modify query, please see the changes , I am searching in all three fields.

Comment: how much time is query taking to produce the result?

Comment: it is around average 100ms